# Manually dispose of class instance in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, memory, garbage-collection, instance, dispose

Yes, I realize `Garbage Collector` takes care of freeing up memory, and I also know of the inefficiencies in clearing up memory manually, however for educational purposes I would like to know how to dispose a class instance in VB.Net.

Comment: Implement the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface on your class and call `.Dispose()` when you want to be rid of it.

Comment: @Adrian Could you please post some code and post it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Note that *free up memory* is not the same as *dispose*. You can't manually free the memory a class instance takes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the example given in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

to use it, you can either use Using block or call Dispose() directly. for example:

```
' use Using Block: 
Using r = New MyResource(100)
    Console.WriteLine(r.ToString())
End Using

' call Dispose directly:
Dim r = New MyResource(100)
Console.WriteLine(r.ToString())
r.Dispose()
```

Comment: Not all the classes implement the `IDisposable` interface, being unable to use the `.Dispose()`. I think the OP asks for a (not recommended) way to do it with the GC.